# Can we replace java Thread using parallel stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Can we replace java Thread using parallel stream? As we can perform multiple operation in parallel using stream then why we need thread pools?

Comment: Give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Parallel streams use Java Threads.

Comment: W.l.o.g. we cannot replaoce `Thread`s with `Stream:parallelStream` since `Thread`s are more versatile. Think, for example, daemon- or background-threads. Not to mention the fact that `Stream`s should operate stateless.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean whether *every* thread use can be replaces by parallel streams?

1. Threadpools existed long before parallel stream.
2. Not every asynchronous problem can be solved by parallel streams.